# on basic theory over $\mathbb{Z}_4$-linear codes

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, coding-theory

I am a bit confused about this example in Huffman and Pless's *Fundamentals in Error-Correcting Codes*. This can be found in Chapter 12:

> Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a nonempty subset of $\mathbb{Z}{}^4_4$
>   with 16 elements/codewords as follows:
>   \begin{equation*}
> \begin{array}{cccccccc}
> 0000 & 1113 & 2222 & 3331 & 0202 & 1311 & 2020 & 3133 \\ 
> 0022 & 1131 & 2200 & 3313 & 0220 & 1333 & 2002 & 3111
> \end{array}
> \end{equation*}
>
> 1. Show that every codeword of C can be written uniquely in the form
>      \begin{equation*}
>    x\mathbf{c}_1 + y\mathbf{c}_2 + z\mathbf{c}_3, 
>    \end{equation*}
>      where
>      \begin{equation*}
>    \mathbf{c}_1 = 1113, \quad \mathbf{c}_2 = 0202, \quad \mathbf{c}_3 = 0022,
>    \end{equation*}
>      $x \in \mathbb{Z}_4$ and $y,z \in \mathbb{Z}_2$.
> 2. Use (1) to show that $\mathcal{C}$ is a $\mathbb{Z}_4$-linear code.

I find the problem baffling since it is (somehow?) not possible to operate (addition or multiplication) an element of $\mathbb{Z}_4$ with an element of $\mathbb{Z}_2$. Can anybody help me understand the problem? Thanks and more power!

Comment: I'm glad that you asked this question. Too many plow through this without realizing that there might be a problem (+1). The key to this operation being well defined is that only such vectors whose components are all even (0s and 2s) can be multiplied by an element of $\Bbb{Z}_2$. Also observe that the addition here is ALWAYS modulo 4 (componentwise). Case in point: the vectors $c_2$ and $c_3$ can be multiplied by an element of $\Bbb{Z}_2$. The reason is that (modulo four) $2c_2=2c_3=0000$. Therefore there will be no ambiguity! For example $1c_2=3c_2$, so we can view the multiplier modulo $2$.

Comment: Thanks @JyrkiLahtonen!!! Now i understand...